# got the error of renderer fatal error in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

got  'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "users/users/index" while I am calling my users module
here is the code of module.config.php

```
<?php
 return array(
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Users\Controller\Users' => 'Users\Controller\UsersController',
    ),

),

'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'users' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/users[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Users\Controller\Users',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),

'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'users' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
);
```

when I call localhost/myprj/public/users

it is going on my userscontroller.php in indexAction here is the code of controller.

```
public function indexAction()
{ 
    return new ViewModel(array(
            'users' => $this->getUsersTable()->fetchAll(),
        ));
}
```

I got the above fatal error I also created index.phtml underneath module/Users/view/users/users

And here is my index.phtml code

```
 <?php 
     echo "here I am!!";
  ?>
```

any help will be awesome.

Comment: does the template users/user/index exist? Can you post the view code.

Comment: @Ben yes As I said in the question  index.phtml is on this path module/Users/view/users/users/index.phtml and it is working for my other modules but not for this 1 strange :(

Comment: It should a naming convention error. Are you developing on linux platform?

Comment: Yes I am working on linux but I developed other modules by same but it is working fine

Comment: could you please check permission on /Users/view/users/users/ ?  , it must be `755` on your webserver's user , usually the user is `www-data`

Comment: @RajatModi Why are you going to /public in your browser? You need to set that up in your web server for all the redirection work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your module config to this (remove the 'users' key):

```
...
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```